# Are questions about gamma on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

There are comments on this [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/68/is-gamma-still-important-to-take-into-account) suggesting that gamma is off topic due to it being on topic elsewhere. However, I think we need to decide what is on topic here, independently of what is on topic elsewhere.

Should questions about gamma be acceptable here?

Comment: *"off topic due to it being on topic elsewhere"* - That alone is *never* a proper reason, though.

Comment: @ChristianRau Definitely. I'm happy to see it on or off topic (I asked the question on main to prompt this discussion), as long as it's not off topic for *that* reason...

Answer (score 8):

I dont really understand how it could be possible for it to **not** be in scope. It is:

- A graphics hardware related concept
- A mathematical concept
- A image data compression scheme
- Related to producing and computing properly with image data
- often needed for good quality physical shaders to be easy to implement
- affects, filtering and signal procesing in images

etc...

ok so gamma may not be the last word in color correct workflows but still.

Ps: is compression a allowed topic?

Comment: That last sentence sounds like another meta question, or even a prompt for a scope-exploring compression question on main...

Comment: @trichoplax Isn't there already one on JPEG anyway?

Comment: @trichoplax there seems allready be one

Comment: @ChristianRau you're right - I missed that one...

Comment: @joojaa 1 on main but none on meta yet...